# What is the simplest way to make a webapp on AWS?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

Is there an option to start a webapp/webserice on AWS just out of the box by uploading code without installing, configuring and etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) is about a close as you're going to get to this. You will still need to configure a few basic things, but it's pretty easy to get going either with a deployable piece of code (war file) or by checking it out of source control (depending on the language/platform).